# Oracle SQL - Including/excluding specific rows based on logi

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

## Data (for only 1 combination of Customer & Product)

| Customer ID | Product ID | Order ID | Order Date | Order Fulfilled? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123123 | 4444 | 701 | Sep 13, 2022 | 0 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 702 | Nov 15, 2022 | 0 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 703 | Nov 16, 2022 | 0 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 704 | Jan 3, 2023 | 0 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 705 | Jan 31, 2023 | 0 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 706 | Feb 6, 2023 | 1 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 707 | Feb 28, 2023 | 1 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 708 | Mar 29, 2023 | 1 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 709 | Apr 25, 2023 | 1 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 710 | Jul 5, 2023 | 0 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 711 | Jul 12, 2023 | 0 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 712 | Jul 18, 2023 | 0 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 713 | Aug 1, 2023 | 1 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 714 | Aug 15, 2023 | 1 |

## What's needed

Add a new column that will be used to include/exclude rows based on the following logic:

1. **If** 'Order Fulfilled?' = 1 --> **Then** '1' (i.e. include)
2. **If** 'Order Fulfilled?' = 0 AND that order was placed within 30 days before or after a fulfilled order --> **Then** '0' (i.e. exclude)
3. **If** 'Order Fulfilled?' = 0 AND that order was NOT placed within 30 before or after a fulfilled order AND was placed within 30 days before a non-fulfilled order --> **Then** '0' (i.e. exclude)
4. **Else** '1'

Therefore the new column (named 'Include?') should look like this:

| Customer ID | Product ID | Order ID | Order Date | Order Fulfilled? | Include? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123123 | 4444 | 701 | Sep 13, 2022 | 0 | 1 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 702 | Nov 15, 2022 | 0 | 0 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 703 | Nov 16, 2022 | 0 | 1 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 704 | Jan 3, 2023 | 0 | 1 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 705 | Jan 31, 2023 | 0 | 0 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 706 | Feb 6, 2023 | 1 | 1 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 707 | Feb 28, 2023 | 1 | 1 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 708 | Mar 29, 2023 | 1 | 1 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 709 | Apr 25, 2023 | 1 | 1 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 710 | Jul 5, 2023 | 0 | 0 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 711 | Jul 12, 2023 | 0 | 0 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 712 | Jul 18, 2023 | 0 | 0 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 713 | Aug 1, 2023 | 1 | 1 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 714 | Aug 15, 2023 | 1 | 1 |

How to accomplish steps 2 and 3 in the logic above?

I created multiple CTEs, but the outcome is not very accurate, and it's also very performance-extensive.

Comment: Hi - please update your question with what you’ve tried and what specific issue you are facing

Comment: This is probably possible to achieve with window clauses, but for a start it would suffice to use `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` to look up orders before and after: ``case when order_fulfilled = 1 then 1 when exists (...) then 0 when not exists (...) and exists (...) then 0 else 1``.

Comment: "*AND that order was placed within 30 days before or after a fulfilled order*" does this mean ANY OTHER order from the same client? or  ANY OTHER order from the same client for the same product? i.e. please spell out ALL the conditions in full. Also **what version of Oracle?** (this can make a different to what we can propose).

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 variants, neither are exact matches to the expected result, but perhaps these will help you implement the needed conditions.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    Customer_ID NUMBER,
    Product_ID NUMBER,
    Order_ID NUMBER,
    Order_Date DATE,
    Order_Fulfilled NUMBER
);
```

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO my_table VALUES (123123, 4444, 701, TO_DATE('Sep 13, 2022', 'Mon dd, yyyy'), 0)
  INTO my_table VALUES (123123, 4444, 702, TO_DATE('Nov 15, 2022', 'Mon dd, yyyy'), 0)
  INTO my_table VALUES (123123, 4444, 703, TO_DATE('Nov 16, 2022', 'Mon dd, yyyy'), 0)
  INTO my_table VALUES (123123, 4444, 704, TO_DATE('Jan 3, 2023', 'Mon dd, yyyy'), 0)
  INTO my_table VALUES (123123, 4444, 705, TO_DATE('Jan 31, 2023', 'Mon dd, yyyy'), 0)
  INTO my_table VALUES (123123, 4444, 706, TO_DATE('Feb 6, 2023', 'Mon dd, yyyy'), 1)
  INTO my_table VALUES (123123, 4444, 707, TO_DATE('Feb 28, 2023', 'Mon dd, yyyy'), 1)
  INTO my_table VALUES (123123, 4444, 708, TO_DATE('Mar 29, 2023', 'Mon dd, yyyy'), 1)
  INTO my_table VALUES (123123, 4444, 709, TO_DATE('Apr 25, 2023', 'Mon dd, yyyy'), 1)
  INTO my_table VALUES (123123, 4444, 710, TO_DATE('Jul 5, 2023', 'Mon dd, yyyy'), 0)
  INTO my_table VALUES (123123, 4444, 711, TO_DATE('Jul 12, 2023', 'Mon dd, yyyy'), 0)
  INTO my_table VALUES (123123, 4444, 712, TO_DATE('Jul 18, 2023', 'Mon dd, yyyy'), 0)
  INTO my_table VALUES (123123, 4444, 713, TO_DATE('Aug 1, 2023', 'Mon dd, yyyy'), 1)
  INTO my_table VALUES (123123, 4444, 714, TO_DATE('Aug 15, 2023', 'Mon dd, yyyy'), 1)
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```

```
14 rows affected
```

```
SELECT
      Customer_ID
    , Product_ID
    , Order_ID
    , Order_Date
    , Order_Fulfilled
    , CASE 
        WHEN Order_Fulfilled = 1
            THEN 1
        WHEN Order_Fulfilled = 0
            AND (
                EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM my_table t2
                    WHERE t2.Customer_ID = t.Customer_ID
                        AND t2.Product_ID = t.Product_ID
                        AND t2.Order_Fulfilled = 1
                        AND t2.Order_Date BETWEEN t.Order_Date - 30 AND t.Order_Date + 30
                    )
                )
            THEN 0
        WHEN Order_Fulfilled = 0
            AND (
                EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM my_table t3
                    WHERE t3.Customer_ID = t.Customer_ID
                        AND t3.Product_ID = t.Product_ID
                        AND t3.Order_Fulfilled = 0
                        AND t3.Order_Date BETWEEN t.Order_Date - 30 AND t.Order_Date
                    )
                )
            THEN 0
        ELSE 1
        END AS Include
FROM my_table t
ORDER BY
      Customer_ID
    , Product_ID
    , Order_Date;
```

| CUSTOMER_ID | PRODUCT_ID | ORDER_ID | ORDER_DATE | ORDER_FULFILLED | INCLUDE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123123 | 4444 | 701 | 13-SEP-22 | 0 | 0 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 702 | 15-NOV-22 | 0 | 0 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 703 | 16-NOV-22 | 0 | 0 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 704 | 03-JAN-23 | 0 | 0 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 705 | 31-JAN-23 | 0 | 0 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 706 | 06-FEB-23 | 1 | 1 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 707 | 28-FEB-23 | 1 | 1 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 708 | 29-MAR-23 | 1 | 1 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 709 | 25-APR-23 | 1 | 1 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 710 | 05-JUL-23 | 0 | 0 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 711 | 12-JUL-23 | 0 | 0 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 712 | 18-JUL-23 | 0 | 0 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 713 | 01-AUG-23 | 1 | 1 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 714 | 15-AUG-23 | 1 | 1 |

```
SELECT
      Customer_ID
    , Product_ID
    , Order_ID
    , Order_Date
    , Order_Fulfilled
    , CASE 
        WHEN Order_Fulfilled = 1
            THEN '1'
        WHEN Order_Fulfilled = 0 AND SUM(CASE WHEN Order_Fulfilled = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
          OVER (
                PARTITION BY Customer_ID, Product_ID 
                ORDER BY Order_Date
                ROWS BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND 30 FOLLOWING
                ) > 0
            THEN '0'
        WHEN Order_Fulfilled = 0 AND SUM(CASE WHEN Order_Fulfilled = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
           OVER (
                PARTITION BY Customer_ID, Product_ID 
                ORDER BY Order_Date
                ROWS BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
                ) > 0
            THEN '0'
        ELSE '1'
        END AS Include
FROM my_table
ORDER BY Customer_ID
    , Product_ID
    , Order_Date;
```

| CUSTOMER_ID | PRODUCT_ID | ORDER_ID | ORDER_DATE | ORDER_FULFILLED | INCLUDE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123123 | 4444 | 701 | 13-SEP-22 | 0 | 0 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 702 | 15-NOV-22 | 0 | 0 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 703 | 16-NOV-22 | 0 | 0 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 704 | 03-JAN-23 | 0 | 0 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 705 | 31-JAN-23 | 0 | 0 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 706 | 06-FEB-23 | 1 | 1 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 707 | 28-FEB-23 | 1 | 1 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 708 | 29-MAR-23 | 1 | 1 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 709 | 25-APR-23 | 1 | 1 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 710 | 05-JUL-23 | 0 | 0 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 711 | 12-JUL-23 | 0 | 0 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 712 | 18-JUL-23 | 0 | 0 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 713 | 01-AUG-23 | 1 | 1 |
| 123123 | 4444 | 714 | 15-AUG-23 | 1 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/u9I3n4Bo)

Comment: Thank you very much Paul for the 2 variations you provided! Much appreciated. I tried the first one (using "when exists"), and it's working but taking quite a long time. So I am trying to check the performance of the second variation (using partition by), but I came across a problem. The date column I am using in the ORDER BY is a date time field. Thus I noticed that the "preceding" and "following" functions ignore the date, and they just go by the number of rows preceding & following. I tried to use trunc(ORDER_DATE), but it didn't solve the issue. Any thoughts?

Comment: I do not follow you. Preceeding and following do use order by, and ordering on a "date time" column does take the "date" into account.  Are you trying to say that if there are 5 rows in A day, that should only be treated as 1 preceding or following row (i.e. by "some magic" ignore time within a day) . That "magic" would require you to group the data first, then apply preceding/following logic

Comment: NB: This is a good example of why sample data should be accurate and representative of the entire problem. If the column is a timestamp (sub-second accuracy) or date (oracle "date" is accurate to 1 second) should also be specified (e.g. by providing the DDL to create the table)